# How to handle hidden webelement in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium

My Html

```html
<div id="example-1-tab-1" class="responsive-tabs-panel" style="display: block;">
  <div class="freme_box">
   <iframe class="demo-frame" src="dropdown/default.html">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
     <body>
      <select>
         <option selected="" value="">Please Select</option>
         <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
         <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
      </select>
     </body>
    </html>
   </iframe>
  </div>
```

I want to select the value from dropdown list and i have already use select method but it doesn't work. Getting :

> Element not found Exception.

Not sure how to handle this element which is not visible. Any Help?

Comment: Have you considered the fact that the select element is within an iframe and switched to the iframe.

Comment: yes I tried this but i got stuck in   driver.switchTo().frame(0);Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(arg0)) as there is no locator present to locate this

Comment: What is this arg0 that you are passing?  Try searching using By.tagName("select").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `select` element is inside an `iframe` as it seeing in the provided HTML, so you need to switch that `iframe` first before find `select` element as below :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe.demo-frame")));

//Now find the dropdown 
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.tagName("select"));

select.selectByVisibleText("Afghanistan");
```